# Mongoose populate related collections data on find method not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my nodejs app,I have cannot able to fetch multiple collections data in a single find method of mongoose. The collections used were "rooms" and "roomusers" and their models are as follows

rooms collection model

```
var mongoose    = require("mongoose");


// Room Schema
var roomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
                    name : {
                                type : String
                    },
                    slug : {
                                type : String
                    },
                    user :{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
                    date : {
                                type : Date
                    }

});


// This variable can be accessed from outside
var Room = module.exports = mongoose.model(
                                            'Room',//Singular Name of database
                                            roomSchema
                                          );



//Data on database

[{
    "_id": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c771",
    "name": "Room 1",
    "user": "586f2efa79a7bb1498f5abf9",
    "slug": "Room-1",
    "date": "2017-01-11T13:17:01.087Z",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

roomusers collection model

```
var mongoose    = require("mongoose");


// RoomUser Schema
var roomUserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
                    room : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'room' },
                    user : {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
                    date : {type : Date}

});



// This variable can be accessed from outside
var RoomUser = module.exports = mongoose.model(
                                            'RoomUser',//Singular Name of database
                                            roomUserSchema
                                          );

//Data on collection
[{
    "_id": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c772",
    "room": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c771",
    "user": "586e39600e83670e1cd52246",
    "date": "2017-01-11T13:17:01.186Z",
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c773",
    "room": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c771",
    "user": "586e3eba36ee4722c062286b",
    "date": "2017-01-11T13:17:01.190Z",
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c774",
    "room": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c771",
    "user": "586f2efa79a7bb1498f5abf9",
    "date": "2017-01-11T13:17:01.191Z",
    "__v": 0
}, {
    "_id": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c775",
    "room": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c771",
    "user": "5875f82519c5251d9c8318d1",
    "date": "2017-01-11T13:17:01.193Z",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

When I tried to fetch room data it didnt populate roomusers data my find is as follow

```
Room.find({})
.populate('RoomUser') // I tried "roomusers" and "roomuser" still not working
.exec(callback);
#result is as follows
[{
"_id": "5876304d23cd8e2044d5c771",
"name": "Room 1",
"user": "586f2efa79a7bb1498f5abf9",
"slug": "Room-1",
"date": "2017-01-11T13:17:01.087Z",
"__v": 0
}]
```

What I need is to get related roomusers data also from rooms find method. Do I need any additional module for populating related tables? If so how?

Comment: You need to add the key to populate, not the model name. Can you try `.populate('user')`?

Comment: I got the following error when I add .populate('user') :  MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "user".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema) , Please help where I went wrong in the above code

Comment: I got that working Ref: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html   modified  users :{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },   and in populate .populate('users ')

Comment: That's right. The `ref` is case sensitive. If you add your User model, I can add a full answer to your question if interested.